# Security loophole around password changes with .NET FormsAuthentication and persistent cookies?

Tags: asp.net, security, cookies, forms-authentication

OK, here's a scenario:

1. Bob logs into mysite.com, which uses .NET forms authentication, and ticks 'remember me'.
2. Eve steals Bob's laptop
3. Bob gets a new laptop, and changes his password.

Now at this point, Eve has a stolen laptop, which has a persistent cookie stored on it, that will log her in to mysite.com as Bob - and, as far as I can tell, this will work *even after Bob has changed his password*.

By default, the forms authentication cookie doesn't contain Bob's password (whether plaintext, hashed, or otherwise encrypted) - so Bob's password isn't involved in the cookie authentication process at all, and the same username that worked last week will still work today.

It's an easy enough loophole to work around - by simply setting FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("username:passwordHash") or something and then decrypting and splitting the cookie in your authentication handler - but I have trouble believing this issue exists 'out of the box'... am I missing something?

**EDIT**: Note that I'm assuming here that the purpose of a "remember me" button is to stop you having to enter your password every time you visit a website. This works on Facebook, Twitter, Gmail, and practically every other website I can think of - and I'd be very surprised if this isn't the purpose of the 'persistent cookie' option in .NET FormsAuthentication.

Also, yes, I accept that performing two-factor authentication on *every* incoming request incurs a certain overhead, but in real terms it's only marginally more expensive than retrieving the user from the database based on their username, which you'd probably be doing anyway.

**EDIT 2**: It appears that at least one major .NET site - CodePlex.com - is vulnerable to this; see http://codeplex.codeplex.com/discussions/350646

Comment: Shouldn't you compare the data in a cookie with whatever is in database?

Comment: Yes - but the FormsAuthentication cookie contains only the username, and the username isn't affected by the password change...

Comment: When user changes his password, just remove the cookie.

Comment: If your cookie just stores the username, you remember the username when they return to your site and auto-populate it.  You shouldnt be automatically logging them in after they have logged out or the session has timed out(unless the cookie contains the hashed password).

Comment: The cookie should also have a date attached to it, you can compare that date with say an `updated` column on the user table.  That way you can change the `updated` date when the password changes and only accept cookies that are created after that date.

Comment: say to Bod to use password to login to the laptop - and place password to all laptops. Also do not use this "remember me" if you have sensitive data, and ask again to login for thinks that are sensitive. Do not wait all that be done automatically.

Comment: @bobek You're missing the point - the password might be changed on a computer which never had the cookie in the first place - yet the original cookie on the stolen laptop will still work fine.

Comment: Then have an account status column in your table and change it to "ChangedPassword"; while logging in check for the status and if it's not "Active" or something require login.

Comment: Seems to me you're right. I just changed my password on a .NET website and I could still access the website (as a logged in user) from a different computer even after restarting the browser to clear the session. It seems the permanent cookie really is more permanent than you might envisage! Changing the username forced me to have to login again on the next page view as expected... It seems very very odd it doesn't check the password hash in the same way.

Comment: @bobek - what happens if Bob changes his password, then logs in (thus setting his status to 'Active'), and THEN Eve visits the site on the stolen laptop? The account is active, the cookie is valid - it would grant her access to Bob's account, no?

Comment: Look at @Wiktor's second paragraph. This is a serious security hole that I really never thought of. I guess it'll be best to actually create you own cookie with hashed password and username then compare this to your current database data.

Comment: Well while this can be an issue in certain cases it is NOT serious security hole. I bet that most sites work like this. If the physical device where the cookie is stored is compromised there is nothing a developer can do to prevent access because the thief may access the site even before the user changes the password. By invalidating the cookie you will only reduce the window where the attacker will be able to access the website. This is why sites like PayPal do not have remember me option.

Comment: @Stilgar - I'd consider a thief having full, long-term access to my account on any website, even after I'd changed my passwords, a fairly serious security problem. You're right about PayPal et al not offering a 'remember me' option, but many sites *do* offer this option and in most cases, I suspect the developers have just fallen into the 'pit of success' offered by .NET's built-in authentication framework, and are unaware of the risk...

Comment: @DylanBeattie I bet you that this is not .NET specific thing. If you consider this a serious problem then you'd better not use the "remember me" option at all.

Comment: The ideal solution would be for MS to add an "authenticate password on every request" web.config option, which you could enable for applications which require greater security.

Comment: It really doesn't matter if it's a .NET specific thing or not.

Comment: @regularfry it matters when you claim that most .NET sites on the internet are insecure :)

Comment: that being said I do wonder why there is not such an option for the FormsAuthentication. The Roles Provider has an option cacheRolesInCookie.

Comment: A lot of security guidelines and auditors will suggest that you should only permit login from one browser at a time, and one of the reasons they do this is to prevent this vulnerability. I suspect that some major sites like Google and Twitter actually implement this - I certainly notice that I have to reauthenticate with them more often when I'm switching between machines than otherwise. The trick is to record the user's active session ID in the database.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps it would make sense to only accept FormsAuth tickets issued after your last password reset.

So in Global.asax AuthenticateRequest, extract the FormsAuthenticationTicket.IssueDate from the encrypted ticket, and compare it to the date of that users last password reset (you would need to store this in your database when they reset their password).

If the ticket was issued before that date, then reject the ticket, do not authenticate them and ask them to login in again.

I haven't implemented this myself, so I could be missing a hole in the theory somewhere...

Comment: I wonder if the IssueDate of the cookie can be changed from the client or the authentication system will detect it.

Comment: No, the IssueDate is part of the encrypted ticket.

Comment: Yep, the IssueDate is part of the encrypted cookie and so can't be modified by the client - so yes, one solution here would be to compare the ticket IssueDate to the date when the account password was last changed, and reject any ticket that predates the most recent password change.

Comment: One other thing you could do it improve security - make users enter their password again in order to change the accounts email address. If someone stole your laptop after you last reset your password, you don't want them to be able to change the email address, as this would prevent you from resetting your password. By doing this you should always be able to reset your password via email, and so stop them getting in again (although it may be too late...)

Answer (score 1):

Having a hashed password in the authentication cookie would mean that you have to check it upon every request. This would be inefficient as authentication can be costly.

You could provide an easy "fix" for your concern involving an id in forms cookie user data section. Note that if you create the cookie on your own, you can inject an arbitrary data there, for example the password's record id.

Now, you could add the `AuthenticateRequest` handler in your `global.asax`. You try to retrieve the user data from the cookie and you compare the id retrieved form the cookie with the one in the database. If they do not match, you return an error and/or log the user out of the application.